# SQL WHERE IN from param or variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

**Context**

We are currently in the process of cleaning up an SQL database and we've come across a large amount of Stored Procedures which only have slight differences between them. We wish to consolidate them into a single proc to allow for easier maintenance.

**Problem**

Below are just two examples of the kind of stored procs we're attempting to merge (do note, these are simplified versions, not the actual procs).

***Stored Procedure - Current Bookings***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCurrentBookings]
    @client_FK INT, @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Booking].[bookingDateTime])            [RowNumber],
            [Booking].[booking_PK]      [Booking ID],
            [Booking].[bookingDateTime] [Booking Date],
            [Booking].[bookingDuration] [Duration],
            [Booking].[client]          [Client Name],
            CASE WHEN [Booking].[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (4,8,9,7,16) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    [Unserviced],
    FROM    [Booking]
    WHERE   [client_FK] = @client_FK
            AND [Booking].[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (1,2,14,17)
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] >= @startDate
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] < DATEADD(d,1,@endDate)
            AND [Booking].[deleted] = 0
END
```

***Stored Procedure - Archived Bookings***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectArchivedBookings]
    @client_FK INT, @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Booking].[bookingDateTime])            [RowNumber],
            [Booking].[booking_PK]      [Booking ID],
            [Booking].[bookingDateTime] [Booking Date],
            [Booking].[bookingDuration] [Duration],
            [Booking].[client]          [Client Name],
            CASE WHEN [Booking].[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (4,8,9,7,16) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    [Unserviced],
    FROM    [Booking]
    WHERE   [client_FK] = @client_FK
            AND [Booking].[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (1,2,14,4,9,7,16,13)
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] >= @startDate
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] < DATEADD(d,1,@endDate)
            AND [Booking].[deleted] = 0
END
```

The code which invokes the stored procs is in VB.NET

```
Dim Command As DbCommand = _db.GetStoredProcCommand("SelectCurrentBookings")
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "client_FK", DbType.Int32, ClientID)
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "startDate", DbType.DateTime, StartDate)
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "endDate", DbType.DateTime, EndDate)
Return _db.ExecuteDataSet(Command)
```

As you can see, the only difference between the above stored procs are the values supplied to the WHERE IN.

Is there a way for us to modify this and have the list of values supplied through a parameter or variable?

Comment: You can use [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In thise case you would fill the table-value in VB first (e.g. with 4 rows 1,2,14,17) and replace the IN clause with a join to that table-value parameter. In my link are some examples how to do so.

Comment: Be aware that "SQL Server does not maintain statistics on table-valued parameters." The query plans may get crazy.

Comment: @AlexB. thank you for this suggestion, I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but wouldn't that introduce some concurrency issues? Also Michael stated that query plans may get crazy with this, which is not ideal for us either.

Comment: No there are no concurrency issues. Table-valued parameters are treated like local temp tables. For your performance concern: I would check it before claim it. Even though statistics are not used, it is possible to define a Primary Key. Here is additonal info about [performance](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)

Comment: @AlexB. TVP are table variables, not temp tables. Though in concurrence terms I would agree - there is no risk with using them. They will have an estimated [row count of 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/blogdoezequiel/2012/11/30/table-variables-and-row-estimations-part-1/), unless OPTION (RECOMPILE) is used. This may be close enough to not cause a problem in this case, or may be far enough off to unleash the crazy. Test and see; compare your options.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll definitely test out the options and weigh up the best for us in this case. I now have enough information that I can sink my teeth into and experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objective is to reduce maintenance effort I would humbly suggest that moving data values out of the data layer and hard-coding them in the logic layer, perhaps in several places, is maybe not contributing to this objective.

Removing these explicit values from the queries will remove information the optimiser can use to create a plan. Be careful you replace it with something better else query performance may suffer. I would posit these SPs are separated precisely so unique plans exist for each, especially if the queries are much more complex than is shown. Compare the current plans against each other and whatever you end up with to ensure you haven't regressed.

One option may be to create a new "list" table:

```
ListName  StatusCode
current   1
current   2
...
current   17
archive   1
archive   2
archive   4
...
archive   16
```

Join to this table instead of using an IN clause. Qualify the join by ListName, which is passed as a parameter. A unique clustered index on (ListName, StatusCode) would be good. You may consider creating a filtered statistic for each ListName. Create a foreign key constraint if you hold a master list of status values.

The stored procedure then becomes

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCurrentBookings]
    @client_FK INT, @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, 
    @ListName char(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Booking].[bookingDateTime]) [RowNumber],
            ...
    FROM    [Booking]
    INNER JOIN dbo.List as l
        ON [Booking].[bookingStatusCode_FK] = l.StatusCode
        AND l.ListName = @ListName 
    WHERE   [client_FK] = @client_FK
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] >= @startDate
            AND [Booking].[bookingDateTime] < DATEADD(d,1,@endDate)
            AND [Booking].[deleted] = 0
END
```

The calling code gains a parameter

```
Dim Command As DbCommand = _db.GetStoredProcCommand("SelectCurrentBookings")
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "client_FK", DbType.Int32, ClientID)
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "startDate", DbType.DateTime, StartDate)
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "endDate", DbType.DateTime, EndDate)
_db.AddInParameter(Command, "ListName", DbType.String, "current") //correct type needed
Return _db.ExecuteDataSet(Command)
```

This way meanings for status codes are recorded in one place and good statistics are available to the optimiser. Whether this is faster than the current implementation, only testing can tell.

Comment: We actually do have a Lookup table setup which contains all the possible status codes. I don't quite understand how what you're suggesting would work, mainly around how we'd communicate to the join which status' are archived and which are not, so that it can select the appropriate ones. Are you able to please provide some more information?

Comment: A table of all status codes is good. It can be used to ensure good values in the List table by a FK. Status code 4, for example, is used in both "current" and "archive" queries, so the current table you mention is not sufficient. The new table I propose is required.

Answer (score -1):

> **"We wish to consolidate them into a single proc to allow for easier maintenance."**

I would agree, having multiple stored procedure's that do the same thing except a certain condition can be maintenance *hell*; especially if these are all over the place. Below I have a few different options and or solutions you could try out. With this in mind, I will let you decide how you would like to approach this as each option is different as in execution plans etc.

> **"the only difference between the above stored procs are the values supplied to the WHERE IN"**

**Option One**

- Create a system table for example: **dbo.System_Booking_Status**. This table would only need a few columns: **System_Status_ID (Primary Key)**,**Booking_Status_Code INT NOT NULL** and **Booking_Status BIT NOT NULL**

Now you can populate this table with your values. The booking status column could mean 1 for current and 2 for archive; however you wish. Or make it a `VarChar(15)` type and use a description (Current or Archived) so it is distinguished OR a `Char(1)` type and use (**C** - for current & **A** - for archive).

Now that you have a system table you ***can join to*** we need to tell the stored procedure to do so and when. I used a new parameter called: **status** which would need to be passed in when you make the call to either get the current and or archived records back.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCurrentBookings]
    @client_FK INT, @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @status INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @status = 1 --current
    BEGIN
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.[bookingDateTime])            [RowNumber],
            b.[booking_PK]      [Booking ID],
            b.[bookingDateTime] [Booking Date],
            b.[bookingDuration] [Duration],
            b.[client]          [Client Name],
            CASE WHEN b.[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (4,8,9,7,16) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    [Unserviced],
    FROM    [Booking] b
    INNER JOIN dbo.System_Booking_Status sbs
    ON sbs.Booking_Status_Code = b.bookingStatusCode_FK
       AND sbs.Booking_Status = 1 --current?
    WHERE   [client_FK] = @client_FK
            AND b.[bookingDateTime] >= @startDate
            AND b.[bookingDateTime] < DATEADD(d,1,@endDate)
            AND b.[deleted] = 0
    END
       ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.[bookingDateTime])            [RowNumber],
            b.[booking_PK]      [Booking ID],
            b.[bookingDateTime] [Booking Date],
            b.[bookingDuration] [Duration],
            b.[client]          [Client Name],
            CASE WHEN b.[bookingStatusCode_FK] IN (4,8,9,7,16) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    [Unserviced],
    FROM    [Booking] b
    INNER JOIN dbo.System_Booking_Status sbs
    ON sbs.Booking_Status_Code = b.bookingStatusCode_FK
       AND sbs.Booking_Status = 2 --archived?
    WHERE   [client_FK] = @client_FK
            AND b.[bookingDateTime] >= @startDate
            AND b.[bookingDateTime] < DATEADD(d,1,@endDate)
            AND b.[deleted] = 0
    END
 END
```

Now you do not have to use hard coded values and eliminate the `IN clause` by using the `INNER JOIN`.

**Option Two (Quick n Dirty)**

- Pass in another variable to either determine if you want current or archived records back.

  IF @status = 1....
   BEGIN
   --Normal query executed for active...
   END
      ELSE
   BEGIN
   --Normal query executed for archived...
   END

**Option Three**

You can pass in `XML` of the values that you would need. Parse this `XML` out into a `Table Variable` and then join to this. It would eliminate your `IN` clause and better execution plan as well.

For example:

```
 Declare @Status_Codes XML = ''

 DECLARE @StatusTable TABLE
 (
    Status_Code INT
 )

-- Parse the XML in to the temp table declared above
INSERT INTO @StatusTable(Status_Code)
SELECT  
    xmlData.A.value('.', 'INT')
FROM @Status_Codes.nodes('BookingStatus/StatusCode/Code') xmlData(A)
```

Now you have a `Table Variable` you can join to...

```
 FROM [Booking] b
 INNER JOIN @StatusTable s
 ON s.Status_Code = b.bookingStatusCode_FK
```

Next you have to pass this data in from your function call. You can create a function that would return the formatted `XML` and pass that into your stored procedure call.

```
 Public Shared Function ConstructXMLStatusCodes(ByVal intStatus As Integer) As String
    Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    If intStatus = 1 'active...
    With strBuilder
      .AppendLine("<BookingStatus>")
      .AppendLine("<StatusCode>")
      .AppendLine("<Code>1</Code>")
      .AppendLine("<Code>2</Code>")
      'continue to add more codes...
      .AppendLine("</StatusCode>")
      .AppendLine("</BookingStatus>")
    End With
    Else
      'Create your builder with the archive...
    End If

    Return strBuilder.ToString()
 End Function
```

Then make your call before passing it to your function OR make the call in your function; you have more than a few choices...

**On another Note**

I notice you are executing a `DataSet` but you are never returning one, I would use the `DataTable.Load` method that executes a reader and fills a table...

Good Luck!

Comment: @downvoter please add what could be improved and what is wrong with the answer? It's sad to come along and downvote without explaination. All **3** options will work and have been tested...